# Source of parameters in Before Report Trigger in Oracle Report

Tags: oracle, parameters, triggers, oraclereports

I am currently working on a migration of oracle reports to another report engine. Therefore I need to know where all the data and parameters are coming from.

There is some "before report trigger" defined that, as far as I already found out, will be called before the data is fetched. Some placeholder columns are set by the function of this trigger. So I will also need to run this code in my migrated report.

The function definition looks like this:

```
function BeforeReport return boolean is
  P_id NUMBER;
  P_id2    NUMBER;
  P_id3    NUMBER
```

My question now is: when the reporting engine calls this function before data will be fetched, how does it know what to put into the parameters? Where does this data come from or where is defined, what data will be used here?

I am using Report Builder 12.2.1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

The way you put it, those are not "parameters" but **locally declared variables** (local to that trigger). Check code that follows; I presume that it might look like

```
select e.empno
  into P_id
  from emp e
  where ...
```

or something like that.